# IE9 console gives no clues about js errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I need some advices about IE9 console. I'm pretty comfortable with firebug or webkit console, and I get a lot of advices from them, syntax error, undefined errors, and so on.

trying to get info from IE9 console is like talking to a wall. My page should contains some errors, it's clear to me, but I can't fix them because I don't know what's going on in his head.

The same pages returns few or no error in FF, Webkit or Opera. On IE is a mess, sometimes it works, sometimes not, if I start profiling it works 80% of the time, the remain 20% is broken. There's no difference in console when is working as expected and when is not, in both case I have no errors, and console is void, empty, painful clean.

What's the best pattern to debug javascript on IE?

Comment: I'd go for alert messages in IE as opposed to console.log statements

Comment: @AmitBhargava I'm using if (window.console) console.log(… for my statements but I'm looking for errors! For instance, I've forgotten  a closing ";" before another one, and had no errors in console!

Comment: Leaving off a semicolon isn't necessarily an error - more often than not it _isn't_ an error, so IE9 may be quite correct in not reporting it as one.

Comment: @nnnnnn in that case it was an error, leaving it off have resolved some other glitches.

Comment: The debugger in IE that you get when you press F12 is pretty darn good.  I've never had a case where it didn't show me errors that were occurring unless the code was catching the errors itself so hiding them from the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Firebug Lite. The bookmarklet is very useful.
http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

Comment: Unless they've improved it, Firebug Lite feels a bit awkward compared to current-gen Firebug in Firefox. However, it at least feels familiar and gives you more to go on than IE9's tools.